# Swashbuckle and .Net Core Web API | Readonly swagger schema is not reflecting on yaml for nullable enums

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle, swagger-codegen

I have an object which has nullable enum property along with other properties, just like below.

```
 public class SampleObject
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    [SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("sampleEnum")]
    [SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]
    public SampleEnum? sampleEnum{ get; set; }
}
```

and enum is like

```
public enum SampleEnum
{
    A= 0,
    B= 1,
    C= 2
}
```

SwaggerSchema's name space is **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations** and after generating yaml file.
name has readonly flag but **sampleEnum lacks the readonly attribute.** I have registered the swagger service as well.

[image: SwaggerSchema for name] [image: SwaggerSchema for enum]

Comment: does it happening with nullble objects only?

Comment: yes, I am getting for nullable enums.

Comment: Could someone suggest the way to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

this did the trick:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
options.EnableAnnotations();
options.UseInlineDefinitionsForEnums();
}
```